# C++ Passing a local variable

Tags: c++

I can not figure out where the pointer is wrong in this code. However, I receive the error that the code does not have a pointer-to function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char uppercase (char ch) {
    if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
        return ch - 'a' + 'A' ;
        cout << "Your capital letter is " << ch << endl;
    } else {
        return ch;
        cout << "Your original letter is: " << ch << endl;
    }
}


int main(int& ch){
    cout << "Please enter a lowercase letter between a to z: ";
    cin >> ch;
    char uppercase;
    char outChar;
    char inChar;
    outChar = uppercase(inChar);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You do know that the `return` statements make the function return *immediately*, any code after a `return` won't be executed.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting please?

Comment: int main(int&ch) should be int main() - no need for args at all. And I think you meant cin >> inChar. You don't need char uppercase in your main body. It isn't used locally and will only confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

1. `int main(char&)` is **not** strictly-conforming. It may be provided by the implementation but I don't know of any platform doing this. On a hosted implementation, use `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)` instead.
2. Building up on the 1<sup>st</sup> note, declare `ch` in the function as a local variable and use `char` not `int`:

   ```
   char ch;
   ```

   Or remove it completely, as described in the 4<sup>th</sup> point.
3. You call `uppercase` on an uninitialized variable (`inChar`), resulting in undefined behavior because `uppercase` reads from it. Remove the `ch` variable and use `cin` on `inChar` instead.
4. You should probably exchange the `return ch;` with the `cout`-statement in the `uppercase` function. The `cout`-statement is dead code, meaning it will never be executed because the function returns beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

you have local variable with same name as function name: uppercase
get rid of local variable
also fix main function to following signature.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
....
}

ex:

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char uppercase (char ch) {
  if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
     return ch - 'a' + 'A' ;
  }
  else {
     return ch;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
cout << "Please enter a lowercase letter between a to z: ";

char inChar;
cin >> inChar;
char outChar = uppercase(inChar);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can't you just use char* argv[]?

Comment: indeed you should use `char`, `_TCHAR` is only available on Windows.

Comment: main(int& ch) is definitely wrong. If it compiles it will do something unexpected as ch will not get a memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I can see quite a few problems in your code:

1. Read [Why System is evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/). In short words, using system("pause") tends to be problematic. There are many other ways to make your code stop (e.g. another cin).
2. As one of the above comments stated, the general way of opening the main program is by using int main() or int main(int argc, char** argv).
3. Let's say that your code works... Then you're asking for an executable input "ch" which after that is changed again by asking the same input again during the program's run-time! I proppose that you use point 2. and what @cad said.
4. The true answer to your problem! You are using as an input to uppercase(char) a variable that has not been filled "InChar", but the character you are filling by user input is "ch".

Hope this helps.